# GPO: Allow log on locally, admins access only

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-7, group-policy

I have a small group of desktop servers and I do not want anyone to be able to log on to them locally except for administrators.

We have a Windows 2003 AD and the servers are running Windows 7 Pro.

I know that I can:

Create an OU in AD with said computers, and assign a Group Policy to that OU. Then, in the Group Policy Editor, go to: `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Allow log on locally` and delete all groups/users except for `Domain Administrators, Remote Users, and Administrators`?

Is it better to do this this through Group Policy, or configure this on each machine?

Comment: Please explain your definition of "Log on locally". If the user is a domain user then they won't be able to log on locally to the computer anyway. The exception being if they lose access to the DC, but their credentials are cached. But even so, they'd still be logged on as a domain user.

Comment: Just to be clear. A server running Windows 7 isn't a Server at all.

Comment: correct, a win7 machine is not technically a server but it is used as one by servicing images in a PACS system. It runs 24/7 and no one is suppose to use the computer, except I noticed on the logon screen someone has been using it.

Comment: "Log on locally" is anyone sitting in front of the computer. There are only admin local user accounts, so I need to stop domain users (non-admin) from accessing the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that you mentioned is the best way to do this.

You can configure this on each individual computer, but there's no benefit. Doing it via GPO is much more scalable.

Comment: I noticed after doing the above, the computers host name does not resolve anymore, but the ip does. I can not even ping the computer using the host name... side effect?

Comment: No. I used a similar method to lock down wireless guest accounts that authenticate against AD with no adverse effects. You must have some kind of non-standard config.

Comment: resolving the host name worked the next day.

Comment: @Logman Sounds like you have bad DNS scavenging settings or something completely unrelated to this policy and the two coinciding was a coincidence.